# What is a basic algorithm for related content queries?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have a DB of questions, like SO! When a user has asks a question, I'd like to provide related questions on the sidebar.

Is there a standardized technique for this? Split question by spaces, search on each word, etc... ??

Not really sure where to begin.

Comment: *"Is there a standardized technique for this?"* - No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as **More Like This feature**. [IR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) libraries like Lucene support this feature. [Read here](http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/) for more details.

1. [How MoreLikeThis Works in Lucene](http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/)
2. [Using Lucene and MoreLikeThis to show Related Content](http://cephas.net/blog/2006/11/14/using-lucene-and-morelikethis-to-show-related-content/)

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem like this. First, drop all the glue words: "the, a, an, but, if, cant, can, so, not", etc (probably a huge list)...

What should be left at that point should be mostly nouns and verbs.

Cluster your posts with something like K-Means clustering, against those words. Finally, train a bayes classifier against your clusters and when you get a new post, classify it as like one of your clusters... Finally, return other questions from that cluster....

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to design a table that stores keywords and searches relevant items based on the title of the question. So once a question is entered a hit counter per keyword would define the relevance of the question to some other stored question and with the ranking you can display other questions by highest hits to lowest. That is how I think it is. Hope my idea helps, tried my best so may not be the best answer for you but help it contributes. :)

Answer (score 0):

A naive way would be to query the strings in questions for common words.

For example most of the related questions on this page do have the word *"queries"* or *"algorithm"* in their titles, although they seem to talk about SQL, learning development, and other diverse fields.

So basically you could take one question, split the question string, eliminate stopwords and then try to match as much words as possible on the other question titles.

Once you have a set of questions, where you have matching words in the title, order them by the number of matches or other metrics (for SO e.g. upvotes, answers or viewcount).